# Using Quality metrics of BIRCH Clusters

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

What is significance of quality metrics of BIRCH Clusters Distance3 and Distance4. Appreciate if there are pointers are how to use Average Intra Cluster Distance (D3) and Average Inter Cluster Distance(D4).

Moreover help required how these two measures can be used to determine radius multiplier and far fewer percentage.